# css is lost after inserting new rows

Tags: jquery, css, flexigrid

While populating flexigrid using javascript method (which is in another .js file), unfortunately, the css is lost after I insert new rows. Other sections in the page are ok.

I use the following code:,

```
var newTbl = '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td></tr>';   

$('#flexSwitch > tbody:last').append(newTbl);
```

And the html code I use:

```
<div id="switchGridDiv"  style="width: 100%">
  <table id="flexSwitch" class="flexigrid"> 
   <tbody>

   </tbody>
  </table>          
</div>
```

I can use .css() method of jquery but this will surely take too long when the size of flexigrid css is considered.

Any suggestions, why this might have occurred or any other way how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/XNymc/

Comment: You will need to post more of your jQuery and css. If you could replicate the issue in a http://jsfiddle.net as well that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using flexAddData method of flexigrid solved the issues about css:

```
var data = "{page:1, total:3, rows:["+
                "{id:'id0',cell:['101','A']},"+
                "{id:'id1',cell:['102','B']},"+
                "{id:'id2',cell:['103','C']}"+
                    "]}";

$('#flexSwitch').flexAddData(eval('(' + data + ')'));
```

Thank you for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the > and use ...

```
$('#flexSwitch tbody:last').append(newTbl);
```

?

Also ... remove the extra `<td>` at the end of ...

```
var newTbl = '<tr><td>' + id + '</td><td>' + name + '</td><td></tr>';
```

Comment: The last <td> is not correct of course, but removing it and the > have no effect, everything is still the same.

Comment: Then the problem may be elsewhere ... @Prisoner's jsfiddle example works for me as well